# ubuntu upgrade wants administrative password

Tags: upgrade

Aloha - when selecting 'Upgrade" for 11.10 (in this case) the app loads two files, provides an informational screen, then asks for me to "Enter the Administrative password." I know my username and password (which I use to make other changes) and I am the only user on the server, but my password does not work and I get kicked out after three attempts.  What could this be?

Comment: did you have capslock on or off when it needs to be off or on?

Answer (score 3):

What it wants is the password for root on the server. If you want to test this theory out then open a terminal and run `sudo passwd root` then enter a new password for root. Next time you try the upgrade enter the password you just set. 
The methods described by user58201 should work as well, but didn't exactly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of two methods and see if it still prompts you for an administrative password.  Method one is using Alt+F2 and typing sudo update-manager -d (might be sudo upgrade-manager -d).  Method two is opening a terminal window, and typing sudo do-release-upgrade in.

Hope this helps. Have a great day:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took me a while to discover the root cause:

I created the user manually and the primary group for the user was **not** the per-user group (same name as the user).

1. Run `id` and check if the parenthesized name after "uid" is identical to the group name.

   ```
   uid=1002(myname) gid=1000(myname) groups=1000(myname),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
   ```
2. Then use `usermod` to change the primary group, and make sure you do not lose another group in the process (e.g. **sudo**, which would break the use of `sudo` from your account).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem after fresh install and `sudo update-manager` from terminal worked