# when trying to update 14.10 get message "you are not allowed to preform this action"

Tags: updates, update-manager

upgrade manager will display and start action to upgrade the gives me error that I am do not have privileges to perform this action

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post the exact error message you see on the screen. Did you try this as root?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127679/ubuntu-upgrade-wants-administrative-password.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Something gone wrong in the upgrade process and there is a problem that Ubuntu doesn't ask your admin password to elevate the user privileges.

I didn't know what the problematic package was, so what I did is a full reconfigure-reinstall of every package using the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)'` ; do apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

Save this script as `reinstall_all.sh`

Open a Bash shell, change the script's owner to "root", and make it executable. Like this:

```
sudo chown root:root reinstall_all.sh
sudo chmod 755 reinstall_all.sh
```

And finally execute it:

```
sudo ./reinstall_all.sh
```

Now sit back relax and drink a nice coffee.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693

I hope that helps.